# Android: ActionBar одной кнопкой

Tags: xml, android, java

Имеется активити в стиле Holo. И нужно сделать кнопку для раскрытия меню вверху справа (ActionBar).

Получается, что кнопки меню нету вообще либо как 3 отдельные кнопки меню в ряд, которые даже не влезают в активити (это из-за **android:showAsAction="always"**, но как под другому выводить его я не знаю). В документации сказано, что кнопка ActionBar'a появляется сама.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_reco"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/reco"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_rewrite"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/rewrite"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_delete"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/dell"/>

</menu>
```

Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.blistviewer, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставьте параметр `android:showAsAction="never"`

В офф [документации](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html) об этом написано.

Comment: Тогда меню нет вообще.

Comment: @Ques - Оно есть, но при нажатии кнопки "menu".

Я недавно [решал][1] похожую проблему

[1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/265007/java-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-actionbar-%D0%B2-gmail

Comment: @ua6xh , и как же Вы решили проблему? Мне нужно меню именно в виде тех 3-х точек.

Comment: После обновления приложения Gmail на смарте у меня меню перенеслось вниз по нажатию кнопки меню, на планшете отображается 3 точки как и раньше.

Comment: @Ques, если устройство имеет аппаратную кнопку "меню", вы должны использовать всплывающее снизу меню, вместо `overflow menu`. Почитайте гайдлайны и не ломайте UX.